разница между int и unsigned и структуры в при перердаче в ассемблерную вставку
Есть ли разница передавать int или unsigned или другой 4 байтный тип данных в ассемблерную вставку
Тип так:
int value;
__asm__ __volative__ (
    "int $0x21"
    :: "a"(value)
);

usigned value;
__asm__ __volative__ (
    "int $0x21"
    :: "a"(value)
);

typedef struct 
{
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d;
} mystuct;

mystuct value;
__asm__ __volative__ (
    "int $0x21"
    :: "a"(value)
);

вроде компилятор должен одинаково запихнуть все в eax, но я неуверен

Разницы нет. Машинный код одинаково обрабатывает оба типа.

А почему в EAX, разве в сишке не в стек закидывает?

@сергей семёнов так из стека же можно данные вытащить. Вообще, для примера какая разница в какой регистр пихать пременную?
